# xcode: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 [cout <<]

Tags: c++, xcode

I ran first example of msgpack success in command line, but fail in xcode

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "msgpack::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, msgpack::object)", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o

The error is from this line

```
std::cout << obj << std::endl;  //=> ["Hello", "MessagePack"]
```

I have set the

- Other Linker Flags -lmsgpack
- Library Search Path /usr/local/lib
- C++ Standard Library libc++ with c++ 11 support

Answer (score 4):

This indicates that `obj` has a type `msgpack::object`.

The problem is that there is no `operator<<` for objects of type `msgpack::object`.
What you are looking for is this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, msgpack::object const& data)
{
    // STUFF
}
```

Comment: +1 The likely reason this even compiled is that the operator is *declared* as a friend , but was never implemented as show here.